# "The connection's current state is closed" exception in Windows Service

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Windows Service on Windows Server 2008 R2 which reads some data from database and caches it to a text file, which is served via IIS to clients.

It worked fine until I migrated my database to Windows Server 2012 on different machine in the same server room.

Now the service works, but once in 30 to 60 minutes it crashes with exception 
"ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.".

Here's the code in my database handling library:

```
    public SqlDataReader GetReader(string sp, object parameters, ref object output) {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        using (var command = GetCommand(sp, parameters, ref output)) {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (output != null) SetOutputParameters(command, ref output);
        }
        return reader;
    }

    private SqlCommand GetCommand(string sp, object parameters, ref object output) {
        SqlCommand command;
        command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = sp;
        if (parameters != null) AddParameters(command, parameters);
        if (output != null) AddOutputParameters(command, ref output);
        command.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;
        if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) Connection.Open();
        return command;
    }
```

As you can see, the connection is explicitly open (in `GetCommand(...)` method) if it's state is not already open. I don't close the connection anywhere in my code, because this service queries the database every 500ms.

I have a hunch it has something to do with the company network, because the exception first appeared on the Monday morning after DB migration. When the traffic in company network was low (on weekend and at night) - the service worked properly.

Anyway, am I missing something here? Am I doing something wrong? Should I ever close the connection in such service? Can this exception mask something else? Why does it happen so randomly?

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded service? It seems to me like what you have is a race condition.

Comment: Well, in the same service there is no other thread AFAIK. My DB library has threading support, it creates a separate connection for each thread. But in this specific code there is only one working thread, so exactly one connection should be created and maintained during service's lifetime.

Comment: What about load on the DB? What is the max connection limit and are you checking that? Given this is running every 500ms there is a chance you are flooding the connection pool.

Comment: I agree with @James, I also think that, for some reason the network connection is lost, and the **Connection** enter to an invalid state. Try to wrap **Connection** inside **using**.

Comment: But this should be only ONE connection. I never close it. If the connection pool was exceeded, I think I would receive more relevant exception message. DB is moderately used, there are couple of hundreds connections to it, but it has no connection limits. The new SQL server is much stronger than the last one, with more CPU cores and more memory (16GB).